# Unfortunately (android app) has stopped. null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Hi Whenever I try run this app i get the error message that it has stopped. On the LogCat I get a Null pointer exception on the lines "setUpImage()" in the OnCreate method and the line. "relativeLayout.addView(phone)". I'm just using the images koala and jellyfish as place holders for now so don't worry about those. It's just that the app launches, the image doesn't show up on the screen. Then the app just crashes with that message. I know it's something dumb but it would be really nice if you could please help me... Her is my main activity

---

```
package com.example.togglesilentmode;

import android.graphics.Point;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int displayWidth, displayHeight;
RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
boolean mPhoneIsSilent=true;

private AudioManager mAudioManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

    checkIfPhoneIsSilent();
    setUpImage();

    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

}

//SETTING UP THE IMAGE
private void setUpImage(){

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    displayWidth = size.x;
    displayHeight = size.y;

    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    params.leftMargin = displayWidth/4;
    params.topMargin = displayHeight/4;

    ImageView phone = new ImageView(this);
    phone.setOnClickListener(myOnClickLister);
    phone.setLayoutParams(params);

    if (mPhoneIsSilent) phone.setImageResource(R.drawable.jellyfish);
    else phone.setImageResource(R.drawable.koala);

    relativeLayout.addView(phone);  <----- NULL POINTER EXCEPTION
}

//IMAGE ON CLICK LISTENER
OnClickListener myOnClickLister = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(mPhoneIsSilent) {


mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
            mPhoneIsSilent = false;

            }else {


mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                mPhoneIsSilent = true;

            }
        setUpImage();

    }



};

//CHECK IF PHONE IS SILENT
private void checkIfPhoneIsSilent(){

    int ringerMode = mAudioManager.getRingerMode();

    if (ringerMode == mAudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT) mPhoneIsSilent = true;
    else mPhoneIsSilent = false;
}

//ON RESUME METHOD
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    checkIfPhoneIsSilent();
    setUpImage();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}

And here is my activity_main.xml file.

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `setUpImage` before you retrieved your relative layout. At that time it's still `null`.

So you have to first find your layout and then you can call `setUpImage()`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);


    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

    checkIfPhoneIsSilent();
    setUpImage();

}
```

`NullPointerException` are often easy to solve. Since you identified it, just go through the execution of your code step by step and see why this has not been initialized correctly.